# nginx fastcgi_cache http/https behind a reverse Proxy dosnt work the right way?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, php-fpm, wordpress

Community,

i have a problem to figure out, the right configuration
for the nginx fastcgi_cache.

I have a small Wordpress-Site, it runs on a Virtual Machine, i am using nginx & php7 to serve the Site and nginx as
a reverse Proxy that terminates SSL on a secondary Virtual Machine.

I am using the fastcgi_cache, now i have the Problem that
nginx caches the first hit on my page and after that
it cant decide between http & https.

I the first visitor on the page uses http, all https
visitors gets the http-Version and else http gets the https Version.

I set the fastcgi_cache_key to: $http_x-forwarded-Proto$request_method$host$request_uri;

but that dosnt work :-( Any hints for me?

Thank you
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was the wrong var:

$http_x_forwarded_proto

is much better ;-)